# Moving files in a windows network without a middle man

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a SERVER and a NAS device. I navigated to both of them via Explorer on my laptop. When I did a file drag it looks like the file used my laptop as a middle man to pass thru.

Is there a way to have my laptop not be in the middle so that the files take the direct transfer? It drops the moving a lot when they both sit on GBs connections.

Comment: Does this address your question? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/Dn265282.aspx

Comment: If you don't use RDP, if you have rsync capabilities on both devices, that can save bandwidth if files already exist in both structures.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, use something like RDP to log into the windows server, setup something so you can access the NAS directly, and initiate the file copy/move from the server.

Comment: Indeed, short of a specialized solution (like FTP FXP), the only choice is to “become” one of the parties involved.